# How can I get the Week Index (SUN-0....)

Tags: sql-server, date, week-number

How can I get the Week Index like this

- SUN as 0
- MON as 1
- TUE as 2
- WED as 3
- THU as 4
- FRI as 5
- SAT as 6

from SQL Server.

I have used this

```
SELECT DATENAME(W,GETDATE())
```

But this will return the name as "Friday"

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set datefirst 7
select datepart(dw, getdate())-1
```

[SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

[DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)